bsdtar: Include some specific directories after exclude a wide-ranging pattern
As the question, after researching and tried suggestion from other threads[1][2], but I still not sure how to do it for my use case.
I run a container and regularly backup as tar file.
By redirection stream out from docker export to stdout as stdin of bsdtar, I can filter out some unnecessary files and dirs from the tar file.
docker export $CONTAINER_ID | bsdtar -c --posix -f snapshot.tar \
--exclude=".cache" \
--exclude="Cache" @-

But some cache items are important to speed up imported container after then, I need to include them to my tar file.
docker export $CONTAINER_ID | bsdtar -c --posix -f snapshot.tar \
--exclude=".cache" \
--exclude="Cache" 
--include="some-important-files/.xyz" @-

Command above will result as only those files, because include args have taken precedence than exclude args.
Any suggestion how can I do that?


Exclude files except a specific on in tar - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange
containers - Exclude a directory from podman/docker export stream and save to a file - Stack Overflow

